# Facebook app deleted without any notice

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

My app free daily horoscope was disabled after almost one year. I didn't get any notice from facebook it's just wanish from my facebook developer account.

It didn't have negative feedback - I was regullary check it in apps insights. It has more than 10.000 active users and sudenly dissaper.

The only change I made was this week - I add ads from slovenian provider in it, but the adds has information that they are from someone other not facebook. I also has tos, privacy everything.

Where can I get information why this happened and is there any way to get my app back? I can't make appeal because there is no message from fb.

Grettings
Leo

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

I think you may have fallen fowl of one of the following passages, but you will need to do a little research.

III. Content > 3
"b. You can only utilize advertising or similar monetization related products or services from companies that appear on this list of Advertising Providers within Apps on Facebook.com."
http://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/

VIII. Branding and Promotion Policy

You must follow the guidelines set forth in the Facebook Brand Resource and Permissions Center.
Your app's description, display name and icons must adhere to our Advertising Guidelines.

I hope this is helpful.

Paul